# objective c - how to make color range from blue to red in steps - programmatically

Tags: ios, colors

Using Obj-C, is there a function that can produce color codes that range through the color spectrum in n steps (say 100). The objective is to make UIButtons using these color codes.

I would appreciate ideas on how to proceed. One thought was to take the RGB codes separately and increment each pair.

But perhaps the color codes are in a logical form where I can increment the code in equal steps?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using HEX instead of RGB?

Comment: Thanks Dani. Hex would be fine, are there logical increments?

Comment: I believe you'll have to implement your own code for incrementing HEX values, but it's simple since a HEX code consists of 6 values, 2 for Red, 2 for Green, and 2 for Blue. Values range from 0 to F (Hex counting)

Comment: Do you mean a color interpolation between the 2 colors? Like from red (1,0,0) to blue (0,0,1) having 3 views the middle one would be (.5, 0, .5)...

Comment: Thanks Matic. If you would write this as an answer, but with an example of more steps (10, 100?), that would be perfect.